# Cannot click (other element would get click)

Tags: selenium, input, docusignapi

Java, Selenium, Chrome

While running a test, I received the error above (about other element would receive click).

There are two cases where this happens.  Both in filling out a field from a form.

The first one is where there are several fields to fill out, at least one of which is required.  A very long label (like "required: you must fill in a date") pops up and blocks the "name" field.  I tried, after entering the date (which I have to be sure is first) sending an ENTER but that did not work.

The other is from filling out name, address, city, state, zip, etc, where the STATE field is right next to the CITY field, but the CITY field is longer, and overlaps the STATE field (eclipsing it).  I tried TAB, ENTER and scrolling to the element.

Please see the images.  There is a state box next to "Grand Haven" but it is being eclipsed by the city.

The work around I can occasionally use is to fill the fields in a specific order (state before city) but I am not always afforded that luxury.

This is DocuSign, by the way.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, the scenario isn't clear to me...

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: Sorry I don't think I can share the URL because, even though it is DocuSign, the document contains confidential information.  What question is this a duplicate of?